# Prerendering mui (material-ui) components in react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I have been unable to get `mui` components to work under server-side rendering with react-rails, I have a full issue writeup here. https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/1152

Are there any ways to actually get `mui` to work under server-side prerendering?